# hyperref with the backref=page option

Tags: hyperref, natbib, back-referencing

I encountered an issue when using the `backref=page` option of the hyperref package together with the natbib package with the options `square,sort&compress,numbers`.
If the natbib package compresses a range of references, the middle references does not show the backreference after compiling (latex,bibtex,latex,latex).

See the following short example:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}  
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\begin{document}  
\cite{foo,bar,hole}

\begin{thebibliography}{ab}  
\bibitem{foo} foo

\bibitem{bar} bar

\bibitem{hole} hole

\end{thebibliography}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Make the following patch to natbib.sty:

```
--- natbib.sty.old 2009-07-23 10:44:10.000000000 -0400
+++ natbib.sty  2009-11-01 17:07:53.309765500 -0500
@@ -408,6 +408,7 @@
         \@ifnum{\NAT@nm=\@tempcnta}{%
          \@ifnum{\NAT@merge>\@ne}{}{\NAT@last@yr@mbox}%
         }{%
+           \Hy@backout{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
           \advance\@tempcnta by\@ne
           \@ifnum{\NAT@nm=\@tempcnta}{%
             \ifx\NAT@last@yr\relax
```

I have reported this to the authors of hyperref and natbib. Heiko (author of hyperref) wants this to be fixed in natbib, because this is too deeply buried in the natbib code for him to feel comfortable patching it. Patrick (author of natbib) has not responded to my emails....

Comment: Wouldn't `\@ifundefined{Hy@backout}{}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}}` make it work even without **hyperref**?

Comment: @egreg, that doesn't seem right. Maybe you mean `\@ifundefined{Hy@backout}{}{\Hy@backout{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}}`?

Comment: Yes, of course; I forgot a bit.

Comment: it's probably easiest to just use the `hypernat` package

Answer (score 4):

There's the [hypernat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypernat) package that includes the patch from Lev Bishop's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13701/44530)

```
\usepackage{hypernat}
```

and you should be good.

Comment: this solves the question. Maybe we should mark this answer as solution?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the auxiliary files. Supress the option `sort&compress` and then compile your document as many times as needed in order to generate the citations with their back references; then, add the `sort&compress` option and compile once more to sort and compress the citation list.

Comment: Hmm, this is a very inconvenient workaround as I have to do so whenever I run bibtex, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @adw: it is not so inconvenient (although I understand what you mean): load `natbib` like this: First line:\usepackage[square,numbers%,sort&compress% Second line: ]{natbib} process your document. running (pdf)latex+bibtex+(pdf)latex+(pdf)latex, now uncomment out the option (delete the leftmost %) and run (pdf)latex once more.

Comment: This approach can cause problems. If adding the `sort&compress` changes the pagination (which it certainly can) then you would need to run latex several times for those pagination updates to propagate through to the pagebackrefs (not to mentions table of contents, list of figures, index, `\pageref{}`, etc.)

Comment: @LevBishop: you're right.