# Some page numbers missing in References

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

Writing a scientific document, I noticed that the page numbers (cross referencing) don't always show up in the References section created with bibtex. Actually, the page number is displayed only when the reference number appears explicitly somewhere in the document.

First example: if I have the following citation, "three very important studies [3, 5, 10]", on page 3 of my document then each of the three references will have the "page 3" cross reference in the References section.

Second example: if I have the following citation, "four equally important studies [12-15]", on page 4 of my document then only reference 12 and reference 15 will show the "page 4" cross reference in the References section. References 13 and 14 will have no page number label.

Can someone explain the behavior in the second example? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you please add an MWE to your question, that shows how exactly you produce those backreferences? Assuming that you are using natbib and the backref option of hyperref, the answers to these questions could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13653/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116806/134144

Comment: Switching to biblatex would be an option as well.

Comment: @leandriis yes I do use natbib and hyperref with pagebackref=true. A solution is provided in the first link you shared with the hypernat package. It works for me, thank you.